# DialogForm not working properly - have to press Cancel button twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dialogform with strange behavior - i have to press Cancel button twice (on the first time it returns DialogResult.None and I just cant find the reason of this behavior)

**1. The code to open dialog form**

```
    using (var dlgProcess = new DlgFormProcessMismatches())
        {
            if (dlgProcess.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            else if (dlgProcess.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Process was cancelled...");
            }
        }
```

**2. In the dialogForm i have:**

1) set the "Cancel" button's property DialogResult=Cancel

2)   on the Cancel buttons click event i set DialogResult explicitly (I have tried with and without this, because it should be enough just to set button's Dialogresult=Cancel)

```
    this.DialogResult=DialogResult.Cancel
```

But the problem is, that in the first time i press Cancel button, it returns DialogResult.None, so it shows the dialogForm again and then when i press it again Cancel button returns DialogResult.Cancel

What could be the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong code. You are showing the DialogResult twice. You need to show it once and get the result. Then on the basis of that you can decide what to do. Change it like this

```
DialogResult result = dlgProcess.ShowDialog(this);
if (result  == DialogResult.OK)
{
      // do stuff
}
else if (result  == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
      MessageBox.Show(@"Process was cancelled...");
}
```

Comment: Based on the statement "it returns DialogResult.None, so it shows the dialogForm again" from the question, I would suppose the OP is fully aware of this behavior and has deliberately chosen to implement it like this (?)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper very true. i had the same thoughts afterwords. Waiting for the comment from OP if that is the case.

Comment: :) i guess OP was pressing once and getting the dialog again (second opendialog) so it was confusing the OP

Comment: You are right Ehsan Ullah :) That was a stupid mistake (shame), but this DialogResult.None confused me - if it was DialogResult.Cancel, maybe i would notice the problem myself. (Not sure what OP stands for...)  "it returns DialogResult.None, so it shows the dialogForm again" -> i think i read somewhere that modal form is closed only when it receives valid value and i thought that this is not a valid value and that's why it shows the dialog form the second time

Comment: @Prokurors I am glad that it helped you. OP stands for Original Poster

Answer (score 1):

this will provide you with desired result,you are calling showdialog twice(thats your main problem),instead do this:

```
            var dlgProcess = new DlgFormProcessMismatches();

            if (dlgProcess.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //do stuff.....
            }
            else if (dlgProcess.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Process was cancelled...");
            }
```

problem was you click cancel so it checks for dialogresult.ok and its false it falls through the else which shows the form again and by clicking the cancel that second time it returns cancel to that else if statement.

Comment: "you click cancel so it checks for dialogresult.ok and its false" - ok, now I understand :) Thanks!